# Visual studio code, how to debug simple .js file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So, I've started to code in javascript the other day and found this IDE on web, even tho i use visual studio 2013 pro on daily basis for my programming class at college I can't figure this one out, how can i setup VS code to debug/show where I'm wrong with my code?
Cause you know, every beginner have some trouble with syntax or code logic...

Comment: Are you trying to debug server side or client side JS?

Comment: client side, nothing too complex for sure

Comment: VS Code lets you debug server side code only (correct me if I'm wrong), but  you can use your favorite browser's dev tools to do so. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console should get you started

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407090/visual-studio-code-debugging-client-side-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Found no satisfying solution, so now I'm writing code in VS Code and doing debug in Chrome...